# dynamic content in leaflet popup window

Tags: javascript, leaflet, jquery, dynamic

I can add static html code to a Leaflet popup window but can not load a Dygraph chart into a popup window. How does one load dynamic content into a Leaflet popup window?
Here is a simple jsfiddle with a graph and map. 
https://jsfiddle.net/scottgeowork/pybvvo27/1/

Comment: Did you try using Ajax? here's a nice discussion & example [link](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/947)

Comment: I'm not sure how the discussion relates to my jsfiddle example, the json file is static content in a text file, the dygraph is dynamic and exists in the current web page. Could you modify the jsfiddle to display the dygraph in the popup? I have tried myself but still have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/1k4ujv94/2/

Answer (score 8):

In order to update the popup content I've added an on click function, and used the popup.setContent method.

```
marker.on('click', onMarkerClick );
function onMarkerClick(e) {
   var popup = e.target.getPopup();
   var chart_div = document.getElementById("graphdiv");
   popup.setContent( chart_div );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1k4ujv94/2/