# Change popup content with JavaScript

Tags: leaflet, javascript, popup, html, angular

How can I dynamically change the HTML content of a Leaflet popup using JavaScript?

I have text in the popup that I want to change when it's clicked:

```js
map_layer = L.geoJSON(countries, {
    onEachFeature: this.country_clicked
}).addTo(this.map);

...

country_clicked = (country, layer) => {
    // I spread the popup's HTML over multiple lines for readability:
    layer.bindPopup("<p id='hide' onclick='show_hide()'>
                         Click me
                     </p>

                     <script>
                         function show_hide() {
                             document.getElementById('hide').innerHTML = 'New text...';
                         }
                     </script>"
                   );
}
```

The plain HTML part of the popup works fine, but when I click the paragraph text, my Angular throws an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: show_hide is not defined
onclick map.component.css:1
```

I've seen [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244499/) but their solution makes the function run when the **layer** is clicked, not the popup content.

**Is there a way for me to modify the popup HTML with JavaScript?**

**Edit, full Angular code**:

**map.component.ts**:

```js
export class MapComponent implements OnInit
{
    init_map()
    {
        this.map = L.map("map", { ... });

        this.map_layer = L.geoJSON(this.countries, {
            onEachFeature: this.country_clicked
        }).addTo(this.map);
    }

    ...

    country_clicked(country, layer)
    {
        layer.bindPopup('<p id="hide" onclick="show_hide(this, \'New text ...\')">
                             Click me
                         </p>');
    }

    show_hide(element, txt)
    {
        element.innerHTML = txt;
    }
}
```

But this still throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: show_hide is not defined` error.
I've tried putting the `show_hide()` function everywhere and it still can't be found by the popup:

- Out of the `Map` class
- Within the `Map` class
- Within the `country_clicked` function

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698975/click-link-inside-leaflet-popup-and-do-javascript

Comment: That post is for jquery, but I'm not using jquery.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The point is that stuff in popups doesn't exist *when* you think it does, or *where* you think it does. That includes `<script>`s and stuff like rewriting the definition of a function in a given scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Angular wasn't detecting the `show_hide()` funtion, no matter where I tried putting it. But I was able to achieve what I wanted by embedding the code within the HTML `onclick` definition:

```js
country_clicked(country, layer)
{
    // note the use of BOTH types of quotes: double ( " ) and single ( ' )
    // to create a string within a string
    const new_text = '"New text..."';
    //               ^ outer quotes must be OPPOSITE to the outer quotes below

    layer.bindPopup("<p onclick='this.innerHTML=" + new_text + "'>Click me</p>");
    //                           ^ Update the text directly when clicked
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your `show_hide()` function on global level and then call it with text parameter you want to replace current text with.

Code could then look something like this:

```
 function show_hide(element, txt) {
  element.innerHTML = txt;
 }

country_clicked = (country, layer) => {
  layer.bindPopup('<p id="hide" onclick="show_hide(this, \'New text ...\')">Click me</p>');
}
```

Comment: See my update above. I've tried adding the `show_hide` function everywhere but it still isn't being found.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with Angular and so I can't help you here.

Comment: Thank you the help. I was able to find a solution, I submitted as an answer.